# Is there any flaw in the below design ? My intention is whenever an object is created, unique id has to be generated

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

    private static int counter = 1;

    int uniqueId;

    public Test() {
        uniqueId = counter++;
    }

    public int getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }
}


public class TestSub {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test a = new Test();
        Test b = new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake. I misread the question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : My question is that is there any design fault by using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- the scope of int is large enough for your needs
- you will not work with more than one thread at a time
- you do not need randomness (for security reasons)

it should do exactly what you're describing.